# AWS CloudFormation AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi not available in region ap-southeast-2 (Sydney), but is available through console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to use AWS CloudFormation to manage my stack. I've created ApiGateway APIs through the AWS console before and it has worked fine. However, when I try to add an `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` in my CloudFormation stack template it fails to create the stack with the error `Resource is not supported in this region`.

Why would the result be different between the console and CloudFormation?

Thanks in advance,

Indigo

Answer (score 0):

I already inform AWS CloudFormation team. They should solve this issue shortly. In the meanwhile, please use AWS API Gateway console or SDK to manage your API Gateway resources.

Thanks,

-Ka Hou

Comment: Hi Ka Hou, thanks for doing that! Is there somewhere I can track the progress/know when it is fixed?

Comment: Any update on this? Still seems to be having issues.

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, it is possible to create a CloudFormation resource of type `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` in the Sydney stack. Just tested that out myself by creating a test template in Syndey region:

```
Resources:
  MyRestApi: 
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
    Properties:
      Name: "MyRestAPI"
```

Answer (score 0):

just to add to it, now we have the edge functionality available with AWS, according to which deployment is now not restricted to region specific. With the Edge Functionality you can make your APIs Endpoint to be called from any region after deployed once.
so the CFT for the API to be Region independent can be described as

```
ApiGatewayRestApi:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "API Name"
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - EDGE
      Policy: ''
```

This will make sure the API Endpoint will be available to all the Regions.